# Listview of stateful widgets

Tags: listview, flutter, bloc

I would like to build a list with ListView.builder of stateful widget.

I am building a social network app and I have a list of posts.
Every post has a like button so when I press it, it should be updated in every screen.

So I would like to wrap every post (that is an item in the listview) in a post bloc that can handle the like operation and update itself accordingly.

I don't know if this can be an heavy pattern and if the list will somehow make explode the smartphone of the users.

Comment: Are you looking for a demo or do you encounter any issue? Could you post your code? so we can help.

Comment: Hi thank you. No simply I am asking if it’s a good practice to put StatefulWidgets as items of a listview.

Answer (score 1):

Question :  if it’s a good practice to put StatefulWidgets as items of a listview

Yes. 
example of social network app, You can reference Instagram clone with 215 Stars
https://github.com/mohak1283/Instagram-Clone

Chat screen contains listview 
https://github.com/mohak1283/Instagram-Clone/blob/master/lib/ui/chat_screen.dart

Chat Detail screen is a StatefulWidget
https://github.com/mohak1283/Instagram-Clone/blob/master/lib/ui/chat_detail_screen.dart

[image]